# Set textbox value inside grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Anyone know how to set value textbox inside grid when edit mode is on? 
1. i have textbox name aggregation :
2. i just want to set some value to those textbox when edit mode is on by button. so i have button :
3. i need to define those code in javascript ex setValue() :

```
function setValue() {
    var grid = $('<%=gvVariableConfig.ClientID%>');
    ........(what i need to do is here, anyone help)
    }
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aggregation" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAggregation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AGGREGATION") %>' Width="91%">
                                </asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAggregation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AGGREGATION") %>' Visible="false">
                                </asp:Label>

                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblAggregation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AGGREGATION") %>'>
                                </asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

----------------------------------------------------------------------------   

    <button type="button" style="width: 100%;" onclick="setValue()"> Assign to Aggregation</button>
```

anyone can help?

Comment: try this...use # also in selector function setValue() { var grid = $('#<%=gvVariableConfig.ClientID%>'); ........ }

Answer (score 0):

i think i found some clue to make it solved but i didn't know to get row index when in edit mode.... this is what i do to set value to spesific cells :

```
var grid = document.getElementById('<%=gvVariableConfig.ClientID%>');
              var val = grid.rows[2].cells[6];
              val.textContent = "tes";
```

so my problem now is to get what row user in editing mode. cells index can set static because different button assign to different cells. so hope someone can give some advice about row index in editing mode.

Comment: when try to edit mode, hit the button, text goes to cells, but those textbox become read only and when i hit update, those text didn't save to grid.